# Huawei E3276: disconnect from cell with AT-Command

Tags: at-command, modem

I got a Huawei modem E3276s-150, that I switch in AT command mode with:

```
http://192.168.1.1/html/switchProjectMode.html
```

The modem is connected to a cell.

```
AT+COPS?    
+COPS: 1,2,"26203",2
```

Now I would like to disconnect the modem. On other modems I use the command:

```
AT+COPS=2
```

But the E3276 fails with the Error:

> +CME ERROR: 50

What does the CME ERROR 50 mean ? I can not find any documentation about it.
How do I disconnect the modem from the cell ?

Regards,
David

Comment: Use AT+CMEE=2 to give text errors instead of numeric. Also, AT+COPS=2 should work (it is well-defined in the standard), but I do not have experience with Huawei modems, so maybe their implementation is different or non-conforming?